# Run Cron as non root user

Tags: cron

We use open-shift, and the docker container only could be run as non-root user.

However, the cron failed start with error:

```
seteuid: Operation not permitted
```

I have already done the following settings, the error is still there

```
chmod gu+rw /var/run
crontab -u my_user home/my_user/Base/cron.txt
usermod -a -G root,crontab my_user
```

How to avoid the error?

Answer (score 10):

I use the following to solve the issue.
Hope could be the help to others

```
chmod gu+rw /var/run
chmod gu+s /usr/sbin/cron
# Optional
# chmod g+s, u-s /usr/bin/crontab
crontab -u my_user /home/my_user/cron.txt
```

Comment: Hi Ken (@3944335), I have similar requirements. I have followed all these steps in my Docker file but I am still getting `seteuid: Operation not permitted` while starting cron inside my container. I am using ubuntu-20 as my base image, any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: I am able to run `crontab -u my_user /home/my_user/cron.txt` after adding my user to corntab group but still my script is not running, may be because cron process is running and I am not able to start it because of permission issue

Comment: I also implemented this solution but still I am getting seteuid: operation not permitted.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, running crontab on a noon-root user in docker.

Thank to @Ken, the below command did the trick:

```
chmod gu+rw /var/run
chmod gu+s /usr/sbin/cron
```